# Got hacked and my system won't boot the GUI

Tags: hacknet

I got hacked by Naix and he deleted my GUI. I can only run command lines. How can I recover my GUI?

Comment: I don't have the game but [this](http://steamcommunity.com/app/365450/discussions/0/530649887200318255/#c530649887200359702) steam thread might help.

Comment: @NukesPlus Is *hacking* part of the game *Hacknet* ? Hmm, I wonder.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The game hints at checking your logs. Typing "help" will pull up the commands you need to use.

1. Start out using `cd` to get into your logs folder.
2. Use `ls` to see your log files.
3. Find the IP address that hacked you and type connect followed by
   that IP address.
4. You are now going to use `probe` as usual to begin hacking the
   computer.
5. Run `SSHCrack` and `PortHack`.
6. Use `cd` to go into the sys folder.
7. Use `ls` and you will see he has a system file there for you to use to
   fix your computer.
8. Type `scp x-server.sys` to copy the system file to your computer.
9. Use `dc` to get back to your computer.
10. Type `reboot`

Comment: Do not forget to clean the remote computer logs.

Comment: This doesn't always work, later hackers are behind computers that you would need to proxy overload and other stuff.

Comment: It keeps saying that I got the name wrong but I am dead sure I got it right UPDATE: you need to go to the file (cd <filename>) ls only tells you waht's in it,

Answer (score 5):

You can also get the file from the computer connected to your network. Do the following:

1. Type `Scan` - This should show you the IP of the workstation connected to you
2. Type `connect`
3. find the file that is missing from your computer and copy with `scp`
4. make sure the copied file is moved to your `sys` folder
5. type `reboot -i`