# How do I get my original GUI?

Tags: hacknet

> **Related:** [Got hacked and my system won't boot the GUI](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/231771/got-hacked-and-my-system-wont-boot-the-gui)

So, I got the GUI fixed but now it's a lot different from how it used to be. And I don't like it. Is there any way I can get my original GUI back?

Comment: Vote retracted: there's a slight difference in that this is a follow-up question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So after you get hacked you go get a new one to restore the GUI. Then after you restart and trace down Naix (Nax? I can't remember) you'll find your x-server.sys in his documents. It'll be [Your Username] x-server.sys
> grab it, rename it to x-server.sys then reboot

Comment: Note that you can instead download a different one to use. If you do, then return and get your original one later, it will not be the same as it used to be. It will be the same as what you currently have in use. In doing so, I permanently lost the original layout. To test it, try changing your current one, then download one and replace it. Then repeat. Each file that is named `x-server.sys` on any machine is identical to the one you have currently in use.

Comment: NB: you cannot actually permanently lose the original layout, unless you try very hard to do so – there's a copy of it on at least one another machine.